# AdSupport framework not added in ios5 with xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, xcode4.5

Im integrating FacebookSDK in my app with ios6 and Xcode4.5 .But when I run the app in prevoius versions of XCode (Xcode 4.2 with ios5) I couldn't be able to link Social.Framework and AdSupport.Framework .They are missing and I couldn't find it under Build Phases.Gone through Google and found they are not present in ios5.But when I make those Frameworks as optional .I have made them as optional.But that doesnot work for me .And I couldnot find any turnaround solution to this.

How can I get it worked in xcode4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS started supporting Facebook API which is  Social.Framework is included in iOS 6. It's not available in earlier version for Facebook. You won't get a framework for iOS facebook api in XCode 4.2.

EDIT :

In this case what you have to do is, keep the framework optional which you have already done. Check if Facebook class exists before you call the function. If it does that means user is using iOS 6 or greater version then iOS 6. If it doesn't means user is using iOS version less then iOS 6. To give the reverse compatibility you'll have to implement the Facebook API.

Comment: Can u please tell me then developers using prevoius versions of Xcode wouldn't be able to integrate facebook in their app?

Comment: They can but not using the iOS facebook inbuilt framework. They have to integrate Facebook API. Which is available on Facebook developer site.

Comment: What I want is I have integrated Facebook in ios6.I m running it on another mac with xcode 4.2 .What should I do to run this facebookintegration of ios6 in ios5.Can I modify some settings in ios6 so that it runs in all versions.?I have already made them optional.BUt that doesnot work

Comment: See i've edited my answer. @Sindhia understand this facebook framework is included in iOS 6. It'll not work in iOS 5.